# Android Inflate From an External APK Causes Exception for ConstraintLayout Resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to inflate a layout resource from an APK already installed on my Android device using the following code:

```kotlin
private fun inflateExternalLayout(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val resourceEntryName = "external_layout_name"
        val resourceName = "${EXTERNAL_PACKAGE_NAME}:layout/${resourceEntryName}"
 
        val res = packageManager?.getResourcesForApplication(EXTERNAL_PACKAGE_NAME) ?: resources
        val cntx =
                applicationContext?.createPackageContext(EXTERNAL_PACKAGE_NAME, 0) ?: applicationContext
 
        val layoutId = res.getIdentifier(resourceName, null, null)
        val layout = res.getLayout(layoutId)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate(layout, null) as ViewGroup
        replaceView(fullscreenContent, view)
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        false
    }
}
```

So far LinearLayout, ScrollView, ImageView and all their attributes are resolved successfully, but androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be found.
The problem occurs in `LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate(layout, null) as ViewGroup`
Layout located in the external apk.

The layout looks like the example below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button2_3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button2_6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I attempt to inflate this layout I get the following exception:

```
2021-07-16 14:48:20.004 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
2021-07-16 14:48:20.012 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.resourceexample:layout/layout2: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.resourceexample:layout/layout2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
2021-07-16 14:48:20.013 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.resourceexample:layout/layout2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
2021-07-16 14:48:20.013 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
2021-07-16 14:48:20.013 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.013 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.014 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
2021-07-16 14:48:20.015 14170-14170/com.example.inflaterapp W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
```

I have tried the following to see if I can get around this but none of my workarounds have been successful:

- Include dependencies to both my inflater application and the APK containing the resource layouts

  - Use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`
  - `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'`
- Uses `Constraintlayout` in my app to be sure the object can be resolved by Android.

Comment: Please try to clean build or invalid cache in android studio or  add multidexenabled true in gradle...hope it may help you

Comment: @Ghanshyam just tried, unfortunately the exception was the same :( To be clear, I made the change in both applications.

Comment: Try this in gradle  implementation "android.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"

Comment: Also plz try to check your project and app level gradle properly , may be you are missing the maven or google or jetpack setting